# I'm having trouble executing a MySQL trigger from php

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I cannot get this trigger to run in PHP, even though it works in phpMyAdmin

```
CREATE TRIGGER `check_title` BEFORE INSERT ON `customer` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.title NOT IN     ('Mr','Miss','Ms','Dr','Mrs')THEN
SET @msg := 'Constraint check_title violated';
SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = @msg;
END IF
END
```

I have tried using the DELIMTER $$ command, and tried running it through bother the procedural and object oriented methods.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What error message if any do you get when trying to add the trigger?  Have you tried adding the trigger through the MySQL command client instead of through phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: I'm receiving this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 `. I had it working before by changing the delimiter before and after the trigger, though I understand this does not work through php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have terminating `;` after `END IF`
2. You don't need `@msg` variable at all, especially user (session) variable

That being said your trigger might look

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `check_title` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `customer` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.title NOT IN('Mr','Miss','Ms','Dr','Mrs') THEN
    SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'Constraint check_title violated';
  END IF;
END
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab2be)** demo

---

Now, executing it from php you don't need to change `DELIMITER`, because it's a mysql client command not a SQL statement.

You didn't mentioned what extension (`mysqli_*`, `PDO`, hope not deprecated`mysql_*`) you're actually using, so here is how your php code might look like with `mysqli_*`

```php
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $db->connect_error); //TODO better error handling
}

$sql = "
CREATE TRIGGER check_title 
BEFORE INSERT ON customer 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.title NOT IN('Mr','Miss','Ms','Dr','Mrs') THEN
    SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'Constraint check_title violated';
  END IF;
END";

if (!$db->query($sql)) {
    die('Can\'t create the trigger: ' . $db->error); //TODO better error handling
}

$db->close();

echo 'Trigger successfully created.';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, spent ages trying to get that to work. I was using PDO and have successfully modified my code so that it works using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS testing.check_title$$
USE `testing`$$


CREATE TRIGGER `check_title` BEFORE INSERT ON `customer` FOR EACH ROW
    IF NEW.title NOT IN  ('Mr','Miss','Ms','Dr','Mrs') THEN
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'Constraint check_title violated';
    END IF
$$
DELIMITER ;
```